# Stuck in proving $\overline{f(E)}=f(\overline E)$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $E\subseteq\Bbb R^n$, $f:E\to\Bbb R^m$ a continuous and one-to-one function. Then how to prove that $\overline{f(E)}=f(\overline E)$? Is the hypothesis sufficient? I have attempt to use some sorts of little theorems, such like $\partial E=\overline E\setminus E^\circ$, $f^{-1}(A\setminus B)=f^{-1}(A)\setminus f^{-1}(B)$, etc., but still can't get the result.

Comment: And that's just fine, because the identity is not true in general.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I see!! But I see a textbook use it as a middle step. In order to deduce the result, what assumptions we need to add?

Comment: We can't really guess what assumptions would be relevant to your example.  It would be better if you post the relevant proof, including all necessary context.

Comment: OK, I see. Let me read that again, if I still have the problem, I'll post it tomorrow.

Comment: As you framed it, the question doesn't even make sense. If the domain of $f$ is $E$, then $f(\overline E)$ is undefined (unless $E$ is closed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can show that $f(\overline{E})\subset \overline{f(E)}$, but not the converse (counterexamples have already been given for this).

Each point in $\partial E$ is a limit point of $E$, so choose a sequence $(a_n)$ in $E$ that converges to a general $x\in \partial E$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. By continuity one has $f(a_n)\rightarrow f(x)$, and as each point $f(a_n)$ is an element of $f(E)$, this limit point $f(x)$ is also an element of the closure of $f(E)$.

Comment: Why each point in $\partial E$ is a limit point of $E$? Consider $E=[0,1]\cup\{3\}\subseteq\Bbb R$, then $3\in\partial E$, but we can *not* choose a sequence in $E$ that converges to $3$.

Comment: You certainly can! What about the sequence $(a_n)$ with $a_n=3$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$? Consider a point $x\in\partial E$ and the open ball $B_r(x)$ for $r>0$. This ball intersects $E$ and $E^c$ for all $r>0$ if and only if $x\in \partial E$. With this fact, set $r=1/n$ and choose a point $a_n \in B_r(x)\cap E$, to obtain the sequence $(a_n)$ in $E$ that tends to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let be $f:\Bbb (0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$ and
$$f(x)=\frac1x$$

Let $E=(0,\infty)$.
Then $0\in\overline{f(E)}$ but $0\notin f(\overline E)$. In fact $\overline E$ is not even a subset of the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $n=m=1$, $E = \mathbb{R}^1$, $f(x) = \arctan(x)$.  Then $E$ is closed so $f(\overline{E}) = f(E) = (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ which does not equal $\overline{f(E)}$ since the former is not closed.